# When writing a question, the "Images" help tab should describe how to upload an image

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur, uploader

While entering a couple of my questions, I've wanted to upload an image. Not being familiar with StackExchange's formatting commands, nor with how to upload images, I've clicked the "Images" help tab, which tells how to refer to externally-hosted images. This didn't help me, as I needed a hosting service as well as a way to refer to it.

After some Googling, and searching the interface, I finally found the image icon on the tool bar, which did what I needed. But this all should be simpler.

Just now, while researching this question, I found that clicking the "Image" tab made the image icon bounce a few times. Unless that's a recent change, it wasn't enough to help me. Even if it was a recent change, I still think the "Images" text should include a reference to the image icon. Something like "If your image isn't available at a URL, you can use the imagur hosting service by clicking the XXXX icon on the toolbar."

Comment: I have to ask - what is the images tab? I've never seen it.

Comment: @Oded I think he means the `Images` section that appears when you click the little `?` help icon on the top right of the answer/question box. http://i.stack.imgur.com/vcskR.png

Comment: @Dan But the bouncing does work - what more do you want!?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ah: the whole line of text labels only appears if you click that `?` icon. After that, they're always present for a given site; I'd just assumed they were always there. But, the bouncing icon did NOT work for me; it only bounces for less than a couple of seconds, and I spent those seconds reading all the text revealed by the `Images` button.

Comment: If the `Images` help tab is meant to assist people who want to post an image, why wouldn't it mention that button in its text, rather than just briefly bouncing the button? It's a nice bit of magic, but doesn't help someone (e.g. me) who spends the time to read the help text.

Comment: I've made the question title clearer, as well as improved the text a bit.