# Making a better image uploader

Tags: discussion, images, feedback, imgur, uploader

For those who don't know me, I'm a product designer here at **Stack Overflow**.

Currently I'm working on a project called *Teams* (for more information about Teams and other projects, [read Tim's post on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better)). Some features we're looking to add to Teams require a more feature-rich image uploader. However we don't want to build a better image uploader *just* for Teams. We think this could be a great enhancement for the entire network as it is an item that everyone interacts with regularly.

I did some digging around and you've already been making a number of requests! Below is a list of feature-requests I found this morning:

- [Make all imgur.com links protocol-relative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221304/make-all-i-stack-imgur-com-links-protocol-relative)
- [Allow SVG image uploads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads/273910#273910)
- [Scale down giant photos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho)
- [Explanation for uploading & linking images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176854/explanation-for-uploading-linking-images)
- [Reuse image description (alt text) as hover tooltip (title) by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271135/reuse-image-description-alt-text-as-hover-tooltip-title-by-default)
- [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post)
- [Picture rotation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264100/picture-rotation)
- [Hint the possibility to post image links instead of the actual image for low-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260644/hint-the-possibility-to-post-image-links-instead-of-the-actual-image-for-low-rep)
- [When writing a question, the "Images" help tab should describe how to upload an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260495/when-writing-a-question-the-images-help-tab-should-describe-how-to-upload-an)

**Is there anything else you'd like to add?** I'm sure I missed some. Respond with previous suggestions I've missed or with your own suggestions. Personally I'd love to able to resize and crop an image (this happens a lot with screenshots).

Understand that I can't guarantee what will be worked on or when, but letting us know what you want will help us determine an order. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Integrating the same image uploader in chat would be nice, it's pretty annoying that some features don't work there currently, especially the ability to copy and paste images.

Comment: @Mad agree, chat feels like Area 51 sometimes - old relic that doesn't get any new features anymore.

Comment: Don't forget about chat: [current chat uploader doesn't even mention license requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173448/can-we-get-a-paste-feature-added-to-image-uploads-in-chat) much less allow useful things like paste. Would be really nice to have some consistency, especially if we're getting to be 3 generations out...

Comment: Red freehand circles?

Comment: Thanks for starting from existing feature requests and for asking what we want before building something.

Comment: This would beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Check out some of the other site's metas. We have had questions about image uploading on DIY.

Comment: [Make it usable with the keyboard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269729/image-uploader-is-not-usable-with-the-keyboard)

Comment: Improve the chat image uploader, in particular add copy/paste support.

Comment: Not directly related to the uploader, but it would be nice to [have the uploaded image associated with the user's account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130080/associate-uploaded-images-with-the-uploading-user-account)

Comment: While you're at it, fix the chat image uploader to [impose a sensible file size limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274156/162011).

Answer (score 27):

If the image is above the max size (current 2 MiB), automatically resize (or change compression) to the largest image possible, or close to it.

Comment: … unless it's for [photo.se] or some site that might care about exactitude of artifacts. It's hard to say whether an error, an option to crop, or an option to resize would be most appropriate.

Comment: @200_success: we could give the option to the user

Comment: [imgur's max file size by the way is 20 MB](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-)

Comment: @bobobobo right, but when uploading to imgur via the image uploader embedded within stack exchange, then the limit is only 2 MiB unfortunately.

Answer (score 26):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Something that will be awesome for me is pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> inside the editor while there is an image in the clipboard, and that would automagically open the uploader and paste the image in there.

This will save me so many clicks... :)

Comment: Suppose you have a picture of a unicorn in your clipboard. Do you want it to be put on the wire by mistake or simply selected by the uploader, with no bytes pre-sent? This stuff has privacy ramifications, I'd reckon.

Comment: Then don't press Ctrl+V @deer

Comment: @PatrickHofman - fair enough.

Comment: And **please** make it crystal clear in the uploader itself that *you can actually paste images* - people [get confused a lot about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306951/3764814).

Comment: @Deer pressing CTRL+V or even selecting image directly does not send anything to the server as far as I can tell. Only clicking the submit button actually send the bytes over to the wild, so I'd say the privacy risk is minimal here.

Comment: @Lucas problem is, it's supported only by certain browsers, and not supported by others. There used to be such a message once, until people complained it's wrong because it's not working for their Firefox browser

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, who would've thought [hovering over a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) puts bytes over the wire? With enough JavaScript, anything is possible :) It was mainly tongue in cheek, yet with a few takeaway lessons.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually I believe any file uploaded (or pasted) into the upload image window is automatically uploaded to **imgur**, even if you click cancel on the upload modal.

Comment: @Hynes all I see in the Network tab of the browser's dev tools is some blob request, which doesn't appear to reach any server, only used to preview the picture as far as I can tell

Comment: @ShadowWizard Huh. Okay. Could totally be wrong (and most likely I am). 

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's what browser feature detection is for :-) (assuming this feature is detectable, I don't know what the underlying APIs are)

Comment: @Lucas maybe, but the dev who added it (Oded) once mentioned it's just not worth the time and efforts, and I kind of agree. The paste feature is a nice "hidden" feature. ;)

Comment: @Hynes - oO. Interesting. Could you please re-check? If it uploads the image to imgur before confirmation, this may be against the users' expectations.

Comment: @Joe thanks, but now it cause pasting inside the inline uploader to not work anymore, rather **only** when pasting while uploader is closed. At least for me, it's unintuitive and I really rather still be able to paste while the uploader is open. Any chance to have both options? Also, is this cross browser? I think the original paste was not and supported only by one or two browsers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We are aware of this bug and we're working on fixing it. It is a focus issue.

Comment: @Joe oh, didn't realize it's a bug. Thanks! :)

Comment: This has been implemented as per [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/191655).

Comment: @kenorb yes focus bug is fixed and pasting a URL does trigger the upload process, however it's far from trivial, and nobody really understands it's possible. The uploader just says "Drag and drop or click here to upload", those not familiar with the process have no way to know they can also paste, either actual image or a URL. In the old uploader there was a clear  "upload from web" link, so they made the UX **much worse**, overall.

Comment: @Ghost yes the recalc gave me a push, would have taken few more weeks without it. :)

Comment: @bob please stop removing the tag. It was added offically by someone who was SE employee back then and it's common way to mark things as done when the question itself isn't a clear feature request. If you have an issue with that, please flag the answer and ask a moderator to edit. (I won't roll it back in such case.)

Comment: @GhostCat meh... I don't celebrate anyway. I don't post stuff for the reputation or for the badges. :)

Comment: @Ghost not on meta. Here it means many agree with what I said, even when it didn't really help them. Anyway thanks, and I can't deny it does give a good feeling. ;)

Comment: Agreement is a positive emotion, too. It means that you found words to express what those others were thinking/feeling, too ;-)

Answer (score 21):

I usually do all my post-processing in GIMP, so I have a single request for this:

**Don't force features upon me**. Don't turn our image uploader into a ten-step thing like Gravatar's, where you upload your image then get to rotate it, then crop it, then do whatever else. It should take me fewer than five clicks to upload an image, and that includes selecting it from the filesystem.

Bonus points if you make it even faster: give us a keyboard shortcut (like the current control-G) that opens the image uploader *and* opens the filesystem chooser thing, all in one go. No one wants to break focus when writing a post to upload an image; fewer clicks is good for everyone.

Comment: A thousand times this. That'd be great UX.

Comment: Can you open the file system prompt without a user clicking? That'd be a pretty decent security hole if possible. If that's an option, I'm unaware of it.

Comment: @NickCraver Hadn't thought of that aspect. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21583865/1849664 (I don't claim to be an expert in web stuff), you can do it from a user-triggered event handler. Which I would *think* includes keyboard shortcuts, not sure.

Comment: Speaking of which… I find it annoying that the current shortcut on a Mac (⌘G) conflicts with the Find-next-in-page command.

Comment: @200_success Use control-G :)

Comment: @Undo The problem is not that Ctrl-G works. The problem is that ⌘G is also hijacked, so that I can't Find Next.

Comment: @200_success Ah, gotcha. Hijacking ⌘-* shortcuts is unnatural, I didn't even know SE did that.

Comment: @NickCraver Yes, you can. CTRL-O can do it, so CTRL-G can, too.

Answer (score 9):

Some suggestions from other metas:

DIY: [Change the image upload so that a thumbnail is shown and the full size image linked](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/change-the-image-upload-so-that-a-thumbnail-is-shown-and-the-full-size-image-lin)

DIY: [Please try using smaller versions of images](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/please-try-using-smaller-versions-of-images)

GD: [Can we get SVG support? Do we need it?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/8708) (already requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads/273910#273910) as mentioned in the OP)

Some bugs from other metas:

DIY: [Built-in image uploader falls over](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/built-in-image-uploader-falls-over)

I've made this CW to make it easier for others to add more from their own meta.

Answer (score 8):

It's already been mentioned in the comments, but I want to echo a feature request:

Unify the Q&A image uploader and the chat image uploader

Right now they operate differently from one another. Having the same uploader in both locations would make moving between the two less annoying.

Answer (score 8):

Have a fallback in richness of functionality if a browser doesn't support required features.

As an example of such case see: [Image upload in Opera 12.17 is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305480/image-upload-in-opera-12-17-is-broken)

Specially if the image uploader is standardized between the sites and chat.

Answer (score 8):

Being able to draw on images would be a cool feature!

It isn't *extremely* difficult ([proof](https://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088) :P), but browser compatibility and actual demand for the feature may stop it from happening :(

I can see the feature being used for annotating images and other diagrams - I personally find it tedious to have to open my image editor just to add a bit of text or draw a few circles (which is why I made the above userscript!), so it would be nice to have it built in.

And, it can be used for a bit of fun in chat! ([if it is changed in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273982/260841)... :)

---

If not draw, how about adding text to images instead? This would still let you write a few things on top of images easily!

Answer (score 8):

If the image uploader will be used for any features that require a fixed size (like on the intro image for Company Pages), allow the user to reposition (and maybe also scale up/down and crop) the image once it's uploaded but before it's saved.

Answer (score 6):

If I select a URL and click on the image button, try using that URL as source for the image automatically.

This can be handy for editing in embedded images from URLs added by low rep users.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes on EL&U a small image is all that's necessary, it helps clarify the question or answer. But for some reason, images cannot be centralized, or repositioned. The text that follows is always below the image. I would like the option to wrap the text on either side or place the image in the center. For example, in [this question on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/242815/44619) the image of crayfish was small but it used up a lot of space, space that could have been filled with words!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Provide a documented API, to allow third-party apps to upload images.

Use case: upload images when posting from Emacs.

Use case: one less step when automating the posting of a [geometric figure](https://math.stackexchange.com/), a graph from [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), [TeX output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [a generated graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Sure, this will make misuse of uploaded images easier, but it's already possible now — setting up Selenium for that would be a bother for normal users, but not for spammers. So please provide an easy way to write image uploading scripts and apps.

Comment: There is a workaround which I use for my script which repairs images; I described the solution [here](https://stackapps.com/a/8657/34061).

Answer (score 2):

Right now the image uploader doesn't respect the DPI tag embedded in screen-shots created on high-resolution displays. This cause problems, as I demonstrate in this post: [Bug with display of uploaded screen shots from retina displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275835/bug-with-display-of-uploaded-screen-shots-from-retina-displays).

Comment: That's 100% on imgur side, and I doubt they'll add something like this. Might be, but don't build your hopes too high.

Comment: What's imgur's business model? Are they just a free service that Stack Exchange is using?

Comment: Free only for the visitors, but using its API cost money. I gave answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213547/is-stack-imgur-com-hosting-still-free-for-stack-exchange) with some details, I believe it's still up to date.

Comment: If Stack Exchange is paying to use the API, then you are a paying customer, and your supplier should be concerned about the issue. Alternatively, the Stack Exchange image uploader could examine the PNG, note the DPI, and incorporate a CSS tag so that the image is properly scaled.

Comment: I don't think this in an imgur issue.  Stack Exchange should read the DPI info and display it at 1x or 2x depending on the browser's HiDPI setting.

Answer (score 2):

It should be world class flexible in accept uploading content, no matter what format image data is provided in:

- file
- link to file on web
- blob
- cloud options like dropbox, gdrive
- base64
- .icon

It should have option for quality refining for blurred images.

```
Ctrl v
```

will rock in it.

Comment: It  already supports files and links to images on the web, as well as pasting (CTRL+V) in Chrome browser, which is the only browser where it's technically possible.

Answer (score 2):

The image uploader is kind of slow

That isn't that bad if I can write as it uploads.

But the image upload dialog is now modal -- you can't touch the post text or type while it is uploading. For a 30kB file, it takes about 5 or 6 seconds of staring at the spinner now.

To fix this, make a separate pane to list the images uploaded. Image upload does not freeze text editing but happens on the side. A spinner can be displayed when an upload is happening for those that like to see that type of thing

Tapping the image inserts it into the post at the cursor

[image: image uploader sidepanel]

Answer (score 1):

A way to resize and reposition an image on the screen. So we can put images next to one another. This would make my "how to build this thing in minecraft" style awnsers a lot shorter...

Comment: But this is something that is already possible today and not related to the imageuploader but to how you can leverage markdown? The resizing is also memtioned in Laura's suggestion.

Comment: I think images have to be rezised before the can fit next to each other. Otherwise they would go of the screen

Comment: No, not really because you use the `<img>` tag with their width and height attributes as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 0):

Pictures are often unattributed when they're posted -- so some origin information, like "Uploaded by the user" or "From http://example.com/example.png", might be nice.